# Debuggerd does not produce tombstone info when I register signal handler

Tags: android, java-native-interface, signals

I have a native function to register signal handlers for signals:

```
void register_signal_action() {
    struct sigaction sa;
    struct sigaction old_sa;
    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_sigaction = catch_crash;
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO | SA_ONSTACK;
    if (sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa, &old_sa) != 0) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "test", "register_signal_action failed!");
        return;
    } else {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "test", "register_signal_action signal old action:%p handler:%p", 
                            old_sa.sa_sigaction, old_sa.sa_handler);
    }
}
```

In `catch_crash`, I just log a message and call the old handler:

```
void catch_crash(int signal, siginfo_t *siginfo, void *sigcontext) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "test", "catch_crash: pid:%d|tid:%d|signal:%d|code:%d", getpid(), siginfo->si_pid, siginfo->si_signo, siginfo->si_code);

    call_old_signal_handler(signal, siginfo, sigcontext);
}
```

I call this function in a `Service` process. I manually create an exception which causes a `SIGSEGV` signal. However, the handler function `catch_crash` **is not called** and debuggerd **does not produce tombstone info** in logcat. If I don't call this function, debuggerd produces tombstone info. Does anyone know the reason?